# rails 4 sending "no-cache" for most (but not all) js and css assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to debug an issue with a Rails 4 server where almost all of the JS and CSS assets are being sent to clients with a Cache-Control header of "no-cache".  This despite having the digest properly appended.

I'm not certain, but it may only be those assets that are included by other assets that get the "no-cache" header.

The ones that don't have "no-cache" are (correctly) getting "public, max-age=31536000".

Is there an extra step I need to take for included assets to make them use the right Cache-Control directive?  I'm not a Rails expert nor am I the person who set up this particular server.  Just trying to debug the issue after the fact.

EDITED TO ADD:

It turns out the JS files that are being handled correctly (i.e. "public, max-age=31536000") are the ones explicitly listed in assets/javascripts/application.js.  This file looks like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require jquery-ui
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

All the JS files that are *not* working correctly are located at at paths for the form:

```
/assets/javascripts/dataTables/extras/file.js
```

Comment: post your rails environment config

Comment: have you checked if all asset files are actually included in  config/initializers/assets.rb ? And if you have config.action_controller.perform_caching = true in  config/environments/production.rb ?

Comment: It's in development mode.  I'm also editing the question with more information. I was able to determine what was causing some assets to have "no-cache" and others not.

Comment: Rather, not what was causing it, but *which* files are "no-cache" and which aren't.

Comment: To answer Eugene's questions:  1. There are no assets explicitly listed in assets.rb.  They're getting sent to clients, though, so somehow it's working anyway.  2. perform_caching is set to "false" in environments/development.rb and the server is running in development mode right now.  However, some of the assets still get sent with "Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000", so the perform_caching setting isn't affecting all of them equally.  Every asset explicitly listed in application.js is marked cacheable, whereas the ones pulled in from the "require_tree" are set to no-cache.

Comment: Looks like turning perform_caching on caused the assets currently being sent with "no-cache" to have proper cache settings.  Not sure why the other ones were marked as cachable even when perform_caching was set to "false", but whatever.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Something else weird:  When I put the server in production mode, the assets pipeline kicks in and bundles everything into application.js and application.css, complete with a digest string at the end of the file name.  However, these are sent with no "Cache-Control" header whatsoever.  Which seems weird.  If the files have a digest hash attached, then shouldn't Rails be able to instruct clients to cache them indefinitely?